# Как отправлять картинку файлом python TelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Бот берёт урл картинки и присылает её пользователю, но очень сильно урезается качество самой картинки. Прочитал, что если отправлять не картинку, а файл с этой картинкой, то качество будет урезаться не так сильно. Как мне это сделать? 
Вот кусок кода:

```
  chislo = random.randint(1, len(imgUrls))
  p = (imgUrls[chislo])
  bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [метод](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/README.md#telebot) `send_document`, предварительно [скачав](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229231/python-save-image-from-url/30229298) картинку по указанному url.